# How to get Bazel output base from within rule Args map_each function?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'm writing a Bazel rule which processes an input depsets with lots of jar files in it. My goal is to get the full (absolute) path of the jars for launching an application.

I use `java_binary` for the initial application. However, the application itself later then dynamically loads additional jars into the JVM. I need to give that application the absolute path to those jars.

As the `depset` is pretty expensive to process I want to move that into the execution phase. This requires the use of [Args](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/Args) in combination with a `map_each` function like this:

```
args.add_joined("--jars", dependencies, join_with = ",", map_each = _expand_jars)
```

I'm now stuck with how to turn the jar path into an absolute path. In an older version (which was running in the analysis phase) I passed in the path using a rule attribute. This is required because (for some reason) the bootstrap application couldn't access the jars in the `external/` directory. In the mapping function I have it hard coded to `"bazel-myworkspace/../../"`, which I'd like to get rid of. It does follow the symlink into the exec root and from there I'm able to get to the output base.

```
def _expand_jars(file):
    if file.path.startswith("external/"):
        return "bazel-myworkspace/../../" + file.path
    else:
        return file.path
```

Any ideas?